# How can I see the addres being sent via axios in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, axios

I am trying to send parameters to a web API using axios in nodejs. This is the code snippet I am trying to use:

```
const app = require('axios');

app.get("https://api.somedomain.com/v1/", {
  headers: {
    Param1: 'value1',
    Param2: 'value2',
    Param3: 'value3'
  }
})
  .then((res) => {
    console.log("Executing 'then' block");  // never executes
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    if (err.response) {
      console.log(`response.status: ${err.response.status}`);
    } else if(err.request) {
      console.log(`request.status: ${err.request.status}`);
    }
  })
```

When I execute the above I always get a response code 400 from the catch block.

So my question is this:

Can I display the string which is sent to the web API?  Something that would look like this output:

https://api.somedomain.com/v1/?Param1=value1&Param2=value2&Param3=value3

Sorry if this seems naive but I have been able to make one get to retrieve a URL I will use to send the second get. The first get works and I have the URL. The second one always gives me the 400 response. (Or perhaps, is it because I have executed one get request on the app object and I have failed to clean up the app object to prepare for the next get request?)

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Peter

Comment: You properly want to use query parameters (or query string) instead of headers.

Comment: Now I feel particularly stupid. I have a severe case of tunnel vision and was searching high and low for the complex answer.Thank you for your response.

Comment: Maybe you can try [this solution](https://github.com/axios/axios#query-string) from the docs :)

Comment: Actually, I did what you suggested and it worked like a charm. I kept testing with the exact parameters using a test page and everything had been formatted properly. That kept puzzling me. Once I changed the "headers" to "params" it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from `headers` to `params` in axios config:

```js
const app = require('axios');

app.get("https://api.somedomain.com/v1/", {
  params: { // HERE IS THE CHANGE!
    Param1: 'value1',
    Param2: 'value2',
    Param3: 'value3'
  }
})
  .then((res) => {
    console.log("Executing 'then' block");  // never executes
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    if (err.response) {
      console.log(`response.status: ${err.response.status}`);
    } else if(err.request) {
      console.log(`request.status: ${err.request.status}`);
    }
  })
```

Comment: I did just that, ran it and it worked perfectly (of course). If only we could get the computers to do what we want and not what we tell it .